# PHP Tracking current users

Tags: php, variables

I have an website with editable databases. I am trying to implement a simple system that ensures no one is editing the same row at the same time. I cannot find any information on how to pass PHP variables to different users or how to store them globally on the server.

```
Ex: User 1 is editing Row ABC

User 2 attempts to edit Row ABC

User 2 is warned that someone is editing Row ABC
```

The ideal solution in my mind is

```
User 1 is editing Row ABC -> Create PHP var for that row to lock it

User 2 attempts to edit Row ABC -> A check is done to see if that PHP var exists and its state (0/1)
```

How can I pass this value across to different browser sessions and/or users?

Comment: Assuming you are using MySQL, take a look at row-level locking here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use PHP vars for this. Just store in the database which row is being edited by which user. When a user starts editing a row.

Implement it with a table called `RowLock` and give it 2 columns, `RowId` and `UserId`. Editing a row is:

- Checks if the row is being edited by another user,
- If it is, access is denied
- If it isn't, put the user id in the `RowLock` table and then grant access

When they are finished editing the row, `UserId` is set to null or the the lock is deleted entirely.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this